# Count frequency (Specialized) in Java 8 using Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, java-stream

I have a list of strings like this: "na","na","na","uk","uk". I want to count the frequency of each element in such a way that if the existing map's value is even, then I will add 1; otherwise 2.

```
 List<String> streamer = Arrays.asList("na", "na", "na", "uk", "uk");
 Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();

 for(String s:streamer) {
     if (m.containsKey(s)) {
         if(m.get(s) % 2 == 0)
             m.put(s, m.get(s) + 1);
         else
             m.put(s,m.get(s)+2);
     }
     else
         m.put(s,1);
  }
  System.out.println("CUSTOM Frequency::::" + m);
```

Now, I want to achieve the exact same thing using streams and lambdas.

All I could do is this:

```
Map<String, Long>map4 = streamer.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(),
        Collectors.counting())); // How can I get custom counting instead of Collectors.counting() ?
```

Comment: Note your first method's logic is equivalent to "add `1` if value==0, add `2` if value!=0" (since you never have even numbers), such that your values will be the odd numbers `1, 3, 5, 7, ...` and so on. If this is the intended logic, you could mutate your map after the `Collectors.counting()` like so: `map.replaceAll((k,v) -> v*2 - 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @Sweeper's answer to get the expected counting result, if your question also implied how to customize a collect operation, you could use the method `of()` of the `Collector` class.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)

The method accepts a supplier, an accumulator as a `BiConsumer` and a combiner as a `BinaryOperator`. The supplier simply provides the container where to store the result, in your case a `Map<String, Long>`. The accumulator populates the container by putting or updating an entry with the custom frequency logic. Lastly, The combiner simply merges the sub-results of parallel executions in case the stream is executed as a parallel stream.

```
List<String> streamer = Arrays.asList("na", "na", "na", "uk", "uk");
Map<String, Long> map4 = streamer.stream()
        .collect(Collector.of(
                HashMap::new,
                (Map<String, Long> map, String s) -> {
                    if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
                        map.put(s, 1L);
                    } else {
                        map.computeIfPresent(s, (String key, Long val) -> val % 2 != 0 ? val + 2 : val + 1);
                    }
                },
                (Map<String, Long> map1, Map<String, Long> map2) -> {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
                        map1.computeIfPresent(entry.getKey(), (key, val) -> val + entry.getValue() + 1);
                        map1.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), key -> entry.getValue());
                    }
                    return map1;
                }
        ));
```

##### Output

```
{na=5, uk=3}
```

Comment: Dan, collector is broken because *Combiner* function is not able to merge the two containers in parallel, instead it simply overrides the values mapped to the keys that are common between the two maps.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko you're right! Thanks for letting me notice! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to count the frequency of each element in such a way that if
> the existing map's value is **even**, then I will add `1`; otherwise `2`

To perform a count in the way you've described, instead of creating a *custom collector* or nesting three standard *collectors* one into each other with a combination `groupingBy` + `collectionAndThen` + `counting`, we can do it by using a **single** built-in *collector* `toMap()`.

The code is concise and descriptive:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> oddEvenCount(Collection<String> strings) {
    
    return strings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),                      // key mapper
            str -> 1,                                 // value mapper - executed a key has been encountered first time
            (v1, v2) -> v1 % 2 == 0 ? v1 + 1 : v1 + 2 // merging the values: if existing value is even adding `1`, otherwise `2`
        ));
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(oddEvenCount(Arrays.asList("na","na","na","uk","uk")));
}
```

*Output:*

```
{na=5, uk=3}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/suo)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your custom way of counting always results in a count that is one less than twice the result you would have got from counting normally. You are basically counting each thing as 2 things, except the first thing. The only edge case is 0, where both ways of counting produce the same result, but if it is 0, it won't be put in the map anyway, so we don't actually need to handle that.

We could compute the desired result from `Collectors.counting()` using the `collectingAndThen` collector:

```
var frequency = streamer.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(),
        normalCount -> normalCount * 2 - 1)
    ));
```

Comment: Is there any way I can the control over the maps value ? Like "if map contains this key then do this"... actually I made up this odd even scenario but actual goal was to get the control over the map's key and set as per my need. Could you please check and modify your answer pleaseee?

Comment: @SUVAMROY you can, as in Dan’s answer, but then you would have to consider parallel streams. Your stream would not necessarily produce the same results as your loop if it is parallel. If you have something non trivial that requires checking the existing map’s value, I’d recommend using good old loops.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko regarding Dan’s answer, isn’t that effectively what I said? I just put in less detail about what is wrong: “Your stream would not necessarily produce the same results as your loop if it is parallel.” Should I have made that clearer, or do you mean it is also broken with sequential streams in some way? Your answer is better indeed. I usually rely on the IDE to tell me when I can use `toMap`, but too bad it didn’t tell me that I can do it this time.

Comment: *would not necessarily produce the same results as your loop if it is parallel* - I'm not sure that I've got this part of the comment correctly. Built-in collectors work fine in parallel (even if they are not optimized to be used with parallel streams like `toMap`). *broken with sequential streams* - no, I don't see any pitfalls in the accumulator. Sorry, it's probably incorrect to comment another user's answer under your answer, removing the comment.

Comment: *IDE to tell me* - interesting, never noticed in IntelliJ advice to replace a collector with a different one.